# Can't get pass "this" argument Error with the onClickListner

Tags: android

What am I doing wrong here? I can't get pass "this" argument Error with the onClickListner.

```
 public void onClick(View V){
            txt.setText("Button is Clicked");

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"*804"+encodedHash));

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                return;
            }

            startActivity(i);
        }
```

Comment: Have you implemented `onClick()` listener

Answer (score 0):

Please implement `View.OnClickListener` because you must implement this interface alongside `onClick()` method. Or you can try this code below:

```
public Button btnClick;
btnClick=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_click);

btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  txt.setText("Button is Clicked");

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
        i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"*804"+encodedHash));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide enough information but I think you are getting an error about passing an `OnClickListener` instead of an `Activity` because you're defining an inner anonymous class so `this` refers to this anonymous class.
If want to access your outer/container class you should call it like: `OuterClass.this` or (`this@OuterClass` in kotlin):

```
public void onClick(View V){ txt.setText("Button is Clicked");

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
        i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"*804"+encodedHash));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        startActivity(i);
    }
```